# How to set the value property of a select when using angular

Tags: angularjs

I can successfuly bind an array to a select tag in angular using this syntax:-

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.controller('mainController', [
'$scope',
function ($scope) {

    $scope.testArray = [{ text: '1st', value: 1 }, { text: '2nd', value: 2 }];

}]);
```

My HTML is like this:-

```
<select ng-model="testModel" ng-options="theTitle.text as theTitle.text for theTitle in testArray"></select>
```

However this creates an option list like this:-

```
<select ng-options="theTitle.text as theTitle.text for theTitle in testArray" ng-model="testModel" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <option value="?"></option>
  <option value="0">1st</option>
  <option value="1">2nd</option>
</select>
```

How do you bind the value property in the array to the option value attribute and why does it display the first option as a ?

Is there something else I need to put in my ng-options attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in in html section:

```
<select ng-model="testModel" ng-options="theTitle.text for theTitle in testArray"></select>
```

in javascript section

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);
    mainApp.controller('mainController', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.testArray = [{ text: '1st', value: 1 }, { text: '2nd', value: 2 }];
        $scope.testModel = $scope.testArray[0];
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost gave me the full answer. I just needed to add track by theTitle.value to get the values binding to the array. So I have:- ng-options="theTitle.text for theTitle in testArray track by theTitle.value"

Comment: you can use ng-change to catch action in select tag. Value of your select tag is `$scope.testModel.value`

Answer (score 0):

The reason that ? Is showing is because your ngModel has not been initialized. In mainController, initialize testModel to '1st'. You will see that the ? goes away, and your drop down list is initialized to your first item

Answer (score 0):

In `ng-options`, the format goes `value as alias`, so you need:

```
<select ng-model="testModel" ng-options="theTitle.value as theTitle.text for theTitle in testArray"></select>
```

The `?` option is created because your model value does not exist as an option in the select, so the browser adds it to display the input as empty. To fix it you want to initialise the model to a valid value, something like: `ng-init="testModel = testArray[0].value"`